# Google script string ends with ... and then undefined

Tags: javascript, string, google-apps-script

I'm sure there's a very basic reason for my problem and I hope you'll point it out :)
The problem I have is that a string shows up as ending with "..." on the line of creation but when continuing to the next line it turns into "undefined". Here's an example:

```
var string1 = "sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsfsfsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsfasdfasfasdflkjasldflasdkjflaksdjflasjdflaksjdflasdkjf";
var string2 = "sdfgsdfglksjdflgkjsdlfgkjlsdfgkjlsdkgjlkajsdlfkjladskjflakjdsflkajsdlfkjasdlfkjalsdkfjlaskdjflkasjdf";
var string3 = "sdfglksfdjlgkjsldfgkjlsdfkjglsdfkjglsdkfjglsdkjglsdkgjlsdfkjglsdkfjglsdkfjglsdkjglsdkfjglsdkfjglskfdjglsdkjfg";
var string = string1.concat(string2,string3); // debug breakpoint at this line shows the string as ending with ...
var length = string.length(); // debug breakpoint here shows "string" as undifiend but length apears to be working fine.
```

Any other functions I run on this string return an error as the string is undefined.
Ideas?

Comment: [string.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is not that `string` is undefined. It's that `string.length()` is undefined.

Strings don't have a function `length()` in javascript. They have a property instead `.length`. The ellipsis you're seeing `...` is probably just your console truncating the console output, but the entire string remains. See below.

```js
var string1 = "sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsfsfsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsfasdfasfasdflkjasldflasdkjflaksdjflasjdflaksjdflasdkjf";
var string2 = "sdfgsdfglksjdflgkjsdlfgkjlsdfgkjlsdkgjlkajsdlfkjladskjflakjdsflkajsdlfkjasdlfkjalsdkfjlaskdjflkasjdf";
var string3 = "sdfglksfdjlgkjsldfgkjlsdfkjglsdfkjglsdkfjglsdkjglsdkgjlsdfkjglsdkfjglsdkfjglsdkjglsdkfjglsdkfjglskfdjglsdkjfg";
var string = string1.concat(string2,string3); // debug breakpoint at this line shows the string as ending with ...
var length = string.length; // debug breakpoint here shows "string" as undifiend but length apears to be working fine.
console.log(string);
console.log(length);
```

#### Reference:

- [String length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length)